# Laravel 5-TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53: SOS CALL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, token, laravel-socialite

This error is driving me nuts.  I'm trying to create a retrieve password form and this error keeps getting thrown when I submit it. Token is definitely being provided, so I don't know what is wrong.  This happens only on my local so far. It doesn't happen on production.  And at the same time, not sure if it's related, I get

```
InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 191
```

when i try to login with socialite(google & fb).  One tends to occur when the other occurs.  If I get tokenMismatch from submitting the form and then try to login, I get this error.

Anyway here's the form.  I really need help here

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'PasswordRetrieveController@getUser','id'=>'retrieve-pw-form'])!!}


    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! form::label('email','Email Address')!!}
    {!!Form::text('email','',['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'email','required'=>'required'])!!}

   </div>

{!!Form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn-md btn-default'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Here's the controller.  It never hits my getUser function.  Just throws the tokenMismatch error.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\SecurityQuestions;
use Mail;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PasswordRetrieveController extends Controller{

public function index(){
    return view('password.index');
}

public function getUser(Request $request){
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $user = User::where('email',$email)->first();
    if ($user == null){
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','This email does not exist');
    }
    if(($user->password == null) && (!empty($user->provider))){
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','A password for this email does not exist. Log back in with facebook or google');
    }
    else{
        $tmp_pw = $this->generate_tmp_pw($user);

    return Redirect('password.security_question_1');
    }
}

public function security_questions(){
    echo 1 ;exit;
}

private function generate_tmp_pw($user){
    $tmp_pw= str_random(10);

    $user->tmp_password = $tmp_pw;
    $user->save();
    return $tmp_pw;
}

}
```

Comment: You wrote, you provide the token, but I can't see it in your form. Strange that it works on production, is the csrf verify middleware enabled on the production site? Btw, wrote an aswer.

Answer (score 0):

Csrf token is missing, that is why laravel not accepting it. Add it in your form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'PasswordRetrieveController@getUser','id'=>'retrieve-pw-form'])!!}

    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    //...
```

This will generate a hidden input field with the token in it.

Comment: Token is already generated though when I use Form::open.  Input name token and value is all there when I check inspect element